# Equation. Need to find center of sphere, given three points in space such that sphere is constrained to three points. Comparable to a cradle.

Tags: geometry

Probably impossible without altering the nature of a sphere into an ellipsoid. Essentially I need a formula when given three arbitrary points, configured triangularly yet non-equidistant, to produce a sphere tangent to, or touching all three said constraints in space. Picture a cradle, yet in a configuration different than that of an equilateral triangle, and I must do so retaining the sphere's form. I understand this complicates the entire process, and there will be only one r that will satisfy the tangental three points and keep it a true sphere. I am not sure this is possible, though it might involve topology or mapping somewhere along the line. I've lost sleep over this; whoever can surmise an equation to accomplish the aforementioned will one day thank me.

Answer (score 4):

Let your hree points be $A$, $B$, $C$.  The points equidistant from $A$ and $B$ form a plane.  The points equidistant from $A$ and $C$ form another plane.  Unless the two planes are parallel, they intersect on a line.  Every point on that line is the centre of a sphere that passes through $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique sphere on which three noncolinear points lie. To see this, observe that these three points define a plane $P$ and also a circle $C$ on that plane. It should be obvious that the smallest sphere that satisfies these conditions has $C$ as its equator (i.e., has the same center and radius as $C$). However, the intersection of a sphere and non-tangent plane (if nonempty) is a circle, so it should be clear that any larger sphere can be positioned so that its intersection with $P$ is exactly $C$. Its center will lie on the perpendicular to $P$ through the center of $C$.